# How do I prove that $(x_n) = (2^n)$ does not converge?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

For this question I first attempted by assuming that $(x_n) = (2^n)$ is convergent and that for some $x \in \mathbb{R}$ $(x_n) \rightarrow x$. So, then by defintion of a convergent sequence we have $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq K$ and $|2^n - x| < \epsilon$.

From here onwards I'm stuck with choosing the correct epsilon and finding a contradiction.

Comment: $2^n$ is unbounded and so cannot converge.

Comment: There are infinitely many correct ways to prove this.  You get to take your pick as to your favorite.  Do not think that there is one and only one way to do this, and that you must pick a specific epsilon and such...  For intuition towards one such proof, note that for $m\geq 1$ you have $2^{n+m}\geq 2^{n+1}=2^n+2^n\geq 1+2^n$

Comment: For another such proof, note that $2^n>n$

Comment: So yes I actually have done that by induction. My professor is having us prove $n < 2^n$ as lemma, and then go onto prove that $(2^n)$ is not convergent. I think what I am struggling with is creating a formal for proof for its non-convergence.

Answer (score 0):

As you have said in the comments, if you want to proceed using $2^n>n$, then intuitively the idea is, as $n$ grows to infinity, $2^n$ grows even faster. Suppose $\{2^n\}$ did converge to $x$. Then, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there would be a $K$ such that for $n\geq K$,
$$x-\varepsilon<2^n<x+\varepsilon$$This gives us $n<x+\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq K$. Do you see why that is a problem?

Answer (score -1):

Also without the proposed lemma, by $f(n)=2^n$, let assume $\varepsilon=1$ and wlog $n_0>K\ge 1$ with $|f(n_0) - x| < 1$ then

$$|f(n_0+1) - x|=|f(n_0) - x+2^{n_0}|>2^{n_0}-1>1$$